# Why all the images in a slider first linup for 1-2 secs before they adjust in a proper position?

Tags: php, jquery

if you open this page http://www.expertforyou.com/

All the images  are like vertical for a second or two, before they line up.  Depending on internet speed, it could be a few seconds.

How can we remove this?

Comment: Everything looks fine from Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be avoiding either placing a background-image to the main slider div container (and setting overflow:hidden), so that it shows, for ex, the first image in the sequence, and when the slider finally loads that images is overlapped by..the same image, thus giving the impression of just a longer starting time.

Otherwise, you can wait for all the DOM to be loaded before even display the body of your page.

```
....
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.className += "invisible";
</script>
.....
</body>
```

And in your css:

```
.invisible{ visibility:hidden}
```

The, when DOM is fully loaded, remove the class (place this in your `<head>` section. I'm using jQUery, so be sure to call it before this):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('body').removeClass('invisible');
}
```

Thus showing the whole page, giving the impression of a slight longer server response, at worst. IF javascript is disabled you will just get the usual behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior. The slider kicks in only after the JS is loaded so that people who don't have JS can still use the site. To minimize the disruption, you could add some default styles to the images so that they are floated to the right by default.

Alternatively, you could also completely hide this block of code and display via JS once it has loaded. But this would mean that people with JS disabled won't be able to interact with your images.